# How to remove RFH2 header for a JMS client

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, rfh2

I am using a JMS client. The queue is a IBM MQ. When I write data on the queue, it is added with the RFH header. How can I strip the RFH header. I cannot use IBM MQ apis.

Answer (score 9):

Another way is using the queue URI attributes (http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032240_.htm#q032240___q032240_4).
The attribute `targetClient` controls whether to use RFH or native format.

```
Queue queue = queueSession.createQueue("queue:///" + queueName + "?targetClient=1");
```

Comment: I'm trying to set like below, but eventhough the headers are not reflected at IBM MQ listeners side , i did  with spring boot          from("direct:request").
  setProperty("TARGCLIENT", constant("1")).
  setHeader("JMS_IBM_Character_Set", constant("UTF-8")).

Answer (score 5):

Starting from IBM WebSphere MQ v7, recommended way to tell the Java implementation NOT to generate MQRFH2 headers is to call `MQDestination.setMessageBodyStyle( WMQConstants.WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_MQ)` as `TARGCLIENT` property is only used as a fallback option if `MessageBodyStyle` was explicitly set to `UNSPECIFIED`.

Answer (score 3):

Using JNDI queue configuration you can set targetClient=MQ which has the same effect as targetClient=1:

```
<jmsQueue jndiName="jms/queue/name">
<properties.wmqJms CCSID="819" baseQueueName="MQ.QUEUE.NAME" encoding="273" targetClient="MQ"/>
</jmsQueue>
```

You can also set `PROPCTL` to `NONE` on the queue itself and that will strip the header, though in my experience it's best to do it with application configuration.

Answer (score 2):

In your sender application call `MQDestination.setTargetClient` method with    `WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ` as parameter. This will ensure `RFH2` header is not included in the message.

The other value that can be used for setTargetClient method is `MQJMS_CLIENT_JMS_COMPLIANT`. This indicates that the `RFH2` format is used to send information. Applications that use WebSphere MQ classes for JMS understand the `RFH2` format. Set the `MQJMS_CLIENT_JMS_COMPLIANT` constant when you exchange information with a target WebSphere MQ classes for JMS application.

Answer (score 1):

As some readers landing in this page CAN actually use IBM API, here's my code to publish messages for IBM MQ v8, for legacy clients that do not support RFH header.

```
package com.mycompany.mq.client;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.JMSConsumer;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.compat.jms.internal.JMSC;


public class FileScanner {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("RJEFileParser");

    public final static char CR  = (char) 0x0D;
    public final static char LF  = (char) 0x0A; 

    public final static String CRLF  = "" + CR + LF;     // "" forces conversion to string

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        long m1,m2;

        // Create a connection factory
        JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
        JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

        // Set the properties
        String sHost=Config.get("HOST");
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, sHost);
        logger.info("WMQ_HOST_NAME:"+sHost);

        String sPort=Config.get("PORT");
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT,  Integer.parseInt(sPort));
        logger.info("WMQ_PORT:"+sPort);

        String sChannel=Config.get("CHANNEL");
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL,  sChannel);
        logger.info("WMQ_CHANNEL:"+sChannel);

        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        String sQmgr=Config.get("QMGR");
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, sQmgr);
        logger.info("WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER:"+sQmgr);

        String sAppName=Config.get("APPLICATION_NAME");
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, sAppName);
        logger.info("WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME:"+sAppName);


        boolean bAuth = Boolean.parseBoolean(Config.get("AUTH")); // true
        boolean bMqcsp = Boolean.parseBoolean(Config.get("USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP")); // false
        String sAppUser = null, sAppPass = null;

        logger.info("Auth:"+bAuth);
        if (bAuth) {
            cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, bMqcsp);
            logger.info("USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP:"+bMqcsp);

            if (!bMqcsp) {
                sAppUser=Config.get("APP_USER");
                cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, sAppUser);
                logger.info("APP_USER:"+sAppUser);

                sAppPass=Config.get("APP_PASSWORD");
                cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, sAppPass);
                logger.info("APP_PASSWORD:"+sAppPass);
            }
        }

        // Create JMS objects

        try {
            Connection con;
            logger.info("Creating connection... context: \n"+ cf.toString());
            if (bAuth && !bMqcsp) {
                con = cf.createConnection(sAppUser, sAppPass);
            }
            else {
                con = cf.createConnection();
            }
            con.close(); // connection was created for testing credentials and troubleshooting purposes

            JMSContext context = cf.createContext();


            //Set up the message
            String text = "here goes your payload text" ;
            logger.info("Text:"+text);

            TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage(text);
            // message.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_CHARACTER_SET , 437);
            // message.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_ENCODING , 546);
            message.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PERSISTENCE, Boolean.FALSE);
            JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();

            // create Queue object
            com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue q1 = new com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue();
            q1.setBaseQueueManagerName("MYQUEUEMANAGERNAME");
            q1.setBaseQueueName("MYINPUTQUEUENAME");
            q1.setPersistence(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
            q1.setTargetClient(JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ); // Avoids RFH header!

            // publish the message to queue
            producer.send(q1, message);
            logger.info("JMS message:\n" + message);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. Answers from Stavr00 and Shashi was correct. 
Though I fixed it by using wmq resource adapter. In the configuration for the resource adapter, I used

```
<config-property name="targetClient">MQ</config-property>
```

This is equivalent to setting WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ to the queue.