# removing RFH header from websphere mq

Tags: jmeter, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I'm using jmeter to put message to websphere mq and my another program will pick up that message from mq queue.

When I put manually to mq queue, the message I pick up from my program is exactly the same message I put.

However, when I put message to mq queue using jmeter, the message I pick up from my program became 'RFH :)'. I guess I need to remove RFH header or change the way to put message using Jmeter.

any pointer would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I had similar situation - one system sent MQ messages through my application to another system and there was a possibility that message may have RFH2 header but receiver system could not handle them so it was required to delete them. I used WebSphere Message Broker so I can't say how to delete RFH header in your case (it's very easy it WebSphere Message Broker) but I just want to make you aware that it's also important to change /MQMD/Format to correct value (I used MQSTR) after the deletion of RFH header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove RFH2 header for a JMS client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186558/how-to-remove-rfh2-header-for-a-jms-client)

Comment: thank you @siarheib. I set property control to 'None' for message queue. and It works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thank you @siarheib. I set property control to 'None' for message queue. and It works.