# MQ Message having Junk Characters

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, ibm-mq, jms-topic

I am using JMS API, to send "TextMessage", to a "Queue" created in IBM MQSeries.

When the listener of this queue is picking, sent message, then, my message is prefixed with some garbage characters.

the starting of garbage characters, is having... RFH and MQSTR.

After some analysis, I came to know that, RFH and MQSTR are some "Message Formats".

Can anyone suggest, that do I need to do any changes in my "MessageSender"...pertaining to RFH and MQSTR formats ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove RFH2 header for a JMS client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186558/how-to-remove-rfh2-header-for-a-jms-client)

Comment: Check out the linked to the duplicate question above, it shows several different ways to configure the sender to not add the RFH2 header when the down stream application is not JMS.  I would also note that by the fact that the downstream app is receiving the RFH2 at all indicates it is likely severely backleveled.  Non-JMS applications at MQ v7.0 and later connecting to a MQ queue manager at v7.0 and later normally do not see the RFH2 header because MQ queue managers default behavior is to not present the RFH2 unless it is a JMS app.

Comment: Any version of MQ less that 7.5 is no longer supported and that one goes out of support in April 2018.  v8 and v9 are good candidates to migrate to.