# WSO2: Remove MQRFH2 header from outgoing IBM MQ message

Tags: wso2, ibm-mq

I am facing an issue where the receiving application (consumer/listener of an IBM MQ) cannot handle MQHRF2 format and is expecting the raw MQSTR format instead.

When put a plain old XML message into the queue using WSO2 Integrator (v. 6.1.1), the receiving application sees:

```
RFH     €    zMQSTR      z   <mcd><Msd>jms_text</Msd></mcd>     X<jms>
<Dst>queue://QUEUE_ALIAS</Dst><Tms>1532002363544</Tms><Dlv>2</Dlv></jms>
```

ahead of my XML message which starts right after the JMS tag.

How can I force WSO2 to put MQSTR instead of MQRFH2 into the Websphere MQ? I have tried the following property just before sending via my endpoint but it has no effect.

```
<property name="JMS_IBM_FORMAT" value="MQSTR" scope="transport" type="STRING" action="set"/>
<send>
    <endpoint key="conf:/endpoints/MY_ENDPOINT.xml"/>
</send>
```

The endpoint is merely defined as:

```
<endpoint name="MY_ENDPOINT" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <address format="pox" uri="jms://QUEUE_ALIAS"/>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186558/how-to-remove-rfh2-header-for-a-jms-client

Comment: Hi, the above is referring to JMS clients. This is a specific question relating to WSO2 since we don't have access to the JMS configuration the same way as you would have from Java for example.

Answer (score 0):

The RFH2 header is added by MQ. If you don't need it, add targetClient=1 to the location URI, like:

```
queue:///MYQUEUE?targetClient=1
```

http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?=&p=171236

Comment: Thank you - testing this now and will revert.

Comment: Hi, this did not work. The consumer is still receiving the same headers. Here's the config I tried to add:
<address uri="jms://QUEUE_ALIAS?targetClient=1" format="pox">

Answer (score 0):

Change the queue definition the application gets from as follows:-

```
ALTER QLOCAL(q-name) PROPCTL(NONE)
```

Comment: Thanks, but we do not have access to the queue definitions or ways to change them, so we need application specific way to determine the message type.